# Creating a cell in Matlab that each part of cell has two amount

Tags: matlab, matrix

suppose I have two matrix as mentioned below:

```
A =  17    33    49    65    81    97   113   129   145   161   177

B =  31    57    83   109   135
```

I want to put them in a cell like this:

```
[31, 17]      [57, 17]       [83, 17]      [109, 17]     [135, 17]
[31, 33]      [57, 33]       [83, 33]      [109, 33]     [135, 33]
[31, 49]      [57, 49]       [83, 49]      [109, 49]     [135, 49]
[31, 65]      [57, 65]       [83, 65]      [109, 65]     [135, 65]
[31, 81]      [57, 81]       [83, 81]      [109, 81]     [135, 81]
[31, 97]      [57, 97]       [83, 97]      [109, 97]     [135, 97]
[31, 113]     [57, 113]      [83, 113]     [109, 113]    [135, 113]
[31, 129]     [57, 129]      [83, 129]     [109, 129]    [135, 129]
[31, 145]     [57, 145]      [83, 145]     [109, 145]    [135, 145]
[31, 161]     [57, 161]      [83, 161]     [109, 161]    [135, 161]
[31, 177]     [57, 177]      [83, 177]     [109, 177]    [135, 177]
```

How can I do that in Matlab with C code?

Comment: Using c code in matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Native MATLAB solution

`meshgrid` is sometimes useful to generate a list of all possible pairs of values from different sets:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(B, A);
C = reshape(arrayfun(@horzcat, X(:), Y(:), 'Uniform', 0), numel(A), numel(B));
```

`C` holds the result you're looking for.

#### Example

Let's do an example for the following `A` and `B`:

```
A = [10 20 30 40];
B = [1 2 3];
```

The purpose of `meshgrid` is to create a matrix which duplicates the vectors along dimensions. So vector `B` is duplicated along the first dimension, and `A` is duplicated along the second dimension. The result of `[X, Y] = meshgrid(B, A)` is:

```
X =
    10    20    30    40
    10    20    30    40
    10    20    30    40


Y =
     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3
```

Both vectors are duplicated to produce matrices of equal dimensions.

Regarding `X(:)`, it means that `X` is converted into a column vector, concatenating column-by-column. So `X(:)` results in `[10; 10; 10; 20; 20; 20; 30; 30; 30; ...]`. The same applies to `Y(:)`.

Now the tricky part: `arrayfun` applies a function (in this case `horzcat`, which simply means horizontal concatenation) individually to each element in the input vector. In our case there are two input vectors, `X(:)` and `Y(:)`, so `arrayfun` applies `horzcat` on each corresponding pair of elements, eventually producing all possible combinations of `X` and `Y`.
Also, since each concatenation results is a vector (containing two values), the output of `arrayfun` must be a cell-array, and so a flag called 'UniformOutput' must be set to false.
I suggest that you read more about `arrayfun` in [the official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to understand it better.

The last part is `reshape`, which adjusts the dimensions of the output cell array to match those in your example (number of rows matches the length of `A`, and number of columns matches the length of `B`).

Hope that this clears up this solution a bit.

Comment: Eitan T, I'm new in MATLAB. Would you please explain how does your code work?

Comment: @MohammadKh I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
output = zeros(length(A)*length(B),2);
for i=1:length(B)
  for j=1:length(A)
     output(length(A)*(i-1)+j,:) = [B(i) A(j)];
  end
end
```